# ¿Que query recomendarian para hacer matchmaking entre tablas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Estoy intentando hacer el matchamaking entre dos tablas en ***SQL SERVER***:

- Usuarios
- REPORTE_NOMINA

La idea es que se pueda hacer la relación de las columnas de nombres respectivos de cada tabla y aunque los nombres no sean totalmente similares basándose en los campos, pueda asignar el nombre del departamento al que logre hacer match.

Ej:
La tabla REPORTE_NOMINA tendría el récord:

| Nombre | Departamento |
| --- | --- |
| Jean Pierre Polnareff France | Sistemas |

La tabla Usuarios tendría los campos:

| Nombre | Username | Departamento |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jean Porlnareff | jpolnareff | NULL |

La idea es conseguir una consulta que retorne ambos nombres y el departamento:

| Nombre Nomina | Nombre | Username | Departamento |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jean Pierre Polnareff France | Jean Porlnareff | fila | Sistemas |

*Lastimosamente no se tenía previsto así que no existe un id que permita relacionar las tablas de manera más sencilla.* Y la complejidad estaba en que hay nombres que comparten similitudes entre muchos registros.

Ya se probó con Fuzzy y Metaphone basado en Philips.

***Existe alguna manera o lógica más sencilla para hacer este tipo de búsqueda?*** Ya que debido a los recursos actuales de hardware y la mala estructura original de la base de datos la velocidad de los querys si se atrofia bastante, encima de que luego se tiene que hacer el update a la tabla Usuarios con el resultado.

Comment: El problema no va a estar en los Porlnareff sino en los Gutiérrez y Rodríguez; atinarles es una tarea harto complicada porque no tienes datos auxiliares para validar si es el Rodríguez de Sistemas o el de Contabilidad

Comment: Si, y lo malo es que intenté hacer weighting usando el Fuzzy que probé implementar pero salen matches aun peores. Si mucho pude hacer un match exitoso del 11% de registros. Pero de miles que hay aun está canijo.

Comment: ¿De cuantas filas estaríamos hablando?

Comment: En el servidor ahorita hay 4211 del lado de los Usuarios. En nomina hay 4123. La diferencia son usuarios que tenemos de pruebas y de admin que se usan para los tests de mantenimiento.

Comment: Partamos de la base que no hay un solución real para este tema, si bien no sé la estructura ni los recursos de tu empresa  el volumen no parece que fuera enorme y bien podrías descargar de forma ordenada las dos consultas en planilla de calculo y asignar recursos humanos para hacer el "matching" y que este ya quede registrado en la BD.

Comment: Que tanto varian los nombres? Tienes Ma. en vez de María? En tu ejemplo pones Polnareff y Porlnareff ¿Eso será algo que exista o común? Si ese es el caso, puede ser una tarea más complicada que hacerla a mano.

Comment: No se si estoy perdido, pero ya que la data no es mucha, porque no cambiar la estructura de esas tablas?? Bajan los datos en un Excel, ordenados así como están en las tablas. Luego le agregan los IDs respectivos a las tablas para poder relacionarlas y si **NO** tienen el código del sistema las querys no se verían afectadas por esos nuevos campos, si tienen el código seria aun mas sencillo.

Comment: Si, hice lo que menciona @Patricio, lastimosamente los nombres en la tabla de usuarios no estaban siendo registrados bajo ningún estándar y hay variaciones como menciona Luis, donde hay nombres incompletos, así mismo como homónimos.

Comment: Según recomendación de otro colega, lo mejor en estos casos es una "resanacion" (como cuando tapan grietas en las paredes). Se están haciendo consultas separadas para agrupar datos según criterios varios, en este caso matches de 100% exito, strings homónimos y strings no identificables. Pero es una pérdida de tiempo.  Una lógica que me está ahorrando un poco de trabajo es hacer un parámetro de % de match separando la tabla de referencia en substrings. Cada match acertado completamente añade un score y en base a eso pues logramos filtrar más rápido aunque no menos laboriosamente los datos.